# Will condition block main thread in Node.js?

Tags: node.js

I use socket.io in Node.js.

```
var rooms = {"a", "b"};
io.on('connection', function(client) {  
    socket.on('room', function(room) {
       if(room in rooms){
          socket.join(room);
       }
    });
});

...Code below...
```

Will block condition the main thread and process below:

```
if(room in rooms){
          socket.join(room);
       }
```

I mean, will code below wait the process upper due condition if?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing in your code that waits or blocks the main thread.  Both `io.on()` and `socket.on()` are just installing event handlers.  The rest of your Javascript continues to run and those event handlers will be called some time in the future when the event they are associated with occurs.

The conditional:

```
if(room in rooms){
```

is evaluated at the moment that code runs and immediately executes.  It doesn't wait for anything or block.

We could probably help you better if you told us what the actual problem is that you're trying to solve.

Comment: I need to understand when this situation can appeared, when condition or any part of code can block main thread.

Comment: @Babaev - As I already said, none of the code you showed blocks the main thread.

Comment: @Babaev - If this answered your question, then please indicate that to the community by clicking the green checkmark to the left of the answer.  If not, then please explain which part of your current question has not been answered yet.